# Run Lint from console for only selected files

Tags: android, git, gradle, lint

I am trying to create a custom Git pre-commit hook that checks (using Lint from console, via "gradlew") for possible issues.
However, I can't find how to run Lint only in provided files. If I run something like

```
./gradlew app:lint
```

Lint analyzes all the project files, and this operation can take quite a bit of time.
In [this document](http://tools.android.com/tips/lint/writing-a-lint-check), there is a "Incremental Lint" section, which covers something similar to what I am looking for. I also found this [open issue](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=65405), that is quite the same as my problem, but seems to be more specific, since it "automatically" retrieves the files to be linted.

To sum up: is it possible to run Lint from command line over a collection of files? Or I am just stucked in running it for the whole project?

Best regards

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There is also a dedicated **Lint CLI** available which allows to check particular directories/files [1].

Examples:

```
lint theDirYouWantToCheck/
lint orOneParticularFile.xml
```

With the `--check` option you are also free to limit the checks which are performed. See `lint --help` for more information.

One remark:
If you are facing something like...

```
main: Error: "main" is a Gradle project. To correctly analyze Gradle projects, you should run "gradlew :lint" instead. [LintError]
```

...just `cd` deeper into the directory structure.

1. http://developer.android.com/tools/help/lint.html

Comment: This is quite useful. Thanks! Just a small comment: if `lint` isn't in the path, it should by placed in `%ANDROID_HOME%\sdk\tools`

Comment: Doesn't work. Where should I go deeper when I am layout resource directory?

Comment: Agree with @mallaudin it didn't work on my side either

Comment: What does not work exactly? Do you get an error message?

Comment: when I run it on some file xyz.java, it says task 'xyz.java' not found in project root directory.

Comment: I get following error when i'm using CLI,
myapp: Error: "myapp" is a Gradle project. To correctly analyze Gradle project
s, you should run "gradlew :lint" instead. [LintError]

Comment: What @a11n is trying to say is: when running `/path/to/lint /app/src/main/java/SomeFile.java` gives you the **is a Gradle project** 
 error then `cd /app/src/main` and run lint from here with `/path/to/lint /java/SomeFile.java`

Comment: So I ran the command after getting into the directory in which i want to perform lint like this `...\app\src\main\res>lint layout` But it still gives me that error. `main: Error: "main" is a Gradle project. To correctly analyze Gradle projects, you should run "gradlew :lint" instead. [LintError]
1 errors, 0 warnings
`

Comment: @Kaskasi I tried what you said and it still showed me the same error.