# How do I run standalone lint from Android SDK Tools on a Gradle Project

Tags: android, android-sdk-tools, android-lint

When I try to run the `lint` tool provided in the Android SDK Command Line tools, it fails with the following error

```
build.gradle: Error: "." is a Gradle project. To correctly analyze Gradle projects, you should run "gradlew lint" instead. [LintError]
1 errors, 0 warnings
```

My use case requires me to run the standalone lint in a CI environment with specific checks. How do I get around this error?

Comment: What exact command did you run, which gives you that error?

Comment: nothing much just `lint .` :)

Comment: Have you tried running on a directory like `lint app/`

Comment: Yes. And `res` directory. And also on specific files that I am interested in. All end up with the same error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I searched around for documentation and answers. [Documentation](https://developer.android.com/studio/write/lint#standalone-lint) doesn't have much information on the topic. I had found [one answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29715122/2410641) before posting this question but the provided suggestions around the error didn't work either. In the end, *as Chester said*, it didn't even matter.

Since I am running the tool in a CI environment, I ended up doing the following

```sh
# delete the build.gradle files from the project
find . -type f -name "build.gradle" -exec rm -f {} \;

# run the lint with whatever checks. It works!!
lint --check Whatever .

# stash everything except the deleted files
git add **/*/build.gradle
git stash -k

# stash the deleted files
git stash

# drop the stash with deleted files
git stash drop

# pop the stash with everything else
git stash pop
```

*It's a dirty hack. Always open to better solutions!*